# How do I get the closest distance for each element within a point coordinate table from a polyline table?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Postgres: How do I get the closest distance for each element within a point coordinate table from a polyline table? And if this is possible what version of Postgres is this doable.

Comment: I'd recommend that you post a table definition, some sample data and some expected results. It'll mean people don't have to construct this data in order to test possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any further details on your tables, your best bet is to install [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/), which is the spatial-enablement extension to Postgresql.  PostGIS 2 requires Postgresql 9.1 or higher.  PostGIS 1.x will run on earlier versions of Postgresql but you might as well get the most up to date versions.

Then follow a few [tutorials](http://www.bostongis.com/?content_name=postgis_tut01) so you can cast your tables as GIS point and line features (unless they are already are like that - it's not clear from your post at the time of writing).

Once you have your data and PostGIS set up, use [ST_Distance](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance.html).  You could skip the paragraph above and do it all in the ST_Distance sql command using one of the ST_GeomFromXXX (substitute format for XXX e.g. [ST_GeomFromText](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html)) but that would mean a more complex SQL command (your call). Just be careful with your projections and coordinate systems (which is why a tutorial is useful if you're not familiar with GIS - which is what I am guessing from your query).

Comment: Looking at the command:

Comment: Looking at the command:float ST_Distance(geometry g1, geometry g2);
and the example:SELECT ST_Distance(
  ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-72.1235 42.3521)',4326),
  ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-72.1260 42.45, -72.123 42.1546)', 4326)
 );
to do it for 2 tables one point and the other polyline would I do it this way?  SELECT ST_Distance(select the_geom from pointtable, select the_geom from polylinetable);  This would output the distance of all the points from the polyline table.  Correct?